# MySQL trigger update cursor

Tags: mysql

Как в MySQL получить обновляемую запись в триггере?

Comment: Псевдотаблицы OLD и NEW.

Answer (score 1):

Обратиться к новой записи можно с помощью оператора **NEW**. Например:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkOut BEFORE INSERT ON main 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.nOut < 0) THEN
      SET NEW.nOut = 0;
      SET NEW.trouble = 'Was found an attempt to take less then 0';
    END IF;
  END;
```

Обратиться к уже существуюей записи можно с помощью оператора **OLD**. Например:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTest BEFORE DELETE ON test
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE backup SET row_id = OLD.id, content = OLD.content;
  END;
```